# Jquery - Group array by value and show into textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a array list which I was got form a API call. I was display the list into a textarea by loop through that array.

```
var fileString ="";

var filelist = [
    {"$/Release/branch1/xmlfiles/Checkout.xml"},
    {"$/Release/branch1/xmlfiles/list.xml"},
    {"$/Release/branch1/global/Policy.ascx.designer.cs"},
    {"$/Release/branch1/global/Policy.ascx.cs"},
    {"$/Release/branch1/global/Policy.cs"},
    {"$/Release/branch1/global/img/bgwhite.jpg"},
    {"$/Release/branch1/global/js/init.js"},
    {"$/Release/branch1/global/js/main.js"}
];

for(j=0; j<filelist.length; j++){
  fileString += filelist[j]+ "\n";
}

$('.list').empty().val(fileString);
```

Now I want to group the file list with group by extensions and print into textarea like -

```
UI Files
---------------------------------------
$/Release/branch1/xmlfiles/Checkout.xml
$/Release/branch1/xmlfiles/list.xml
$/Release/branch1/global/js/main.js
$/Release/branch1/global/js/init.js

Dot Net Files
-----------------------------------------
$/Release/branch1/global/Policy.ascx.designer.cs
$/Release/branch1/global/Policy.ascx.cs
$/Release/branch1/global/Policy.cs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group your array based on the extension using the `array#reduce` and then again using `array#reduce` you can generate the string.

```js
var filelist = [ "$/Release/branch1/xmlfiles/Checkout.xml", "$/Release/branch1/xmlfiles/list.xml", "$/Release/branch1/global/Policy.ascx.designer.cs", "$/Release/branch1/global/Policy.ascx.cs", "$/Release/branch1/global/Policy.cs", "$/Release/branch1/global/img/bgwhite.jpg","$/Release/branch1/global/js/init.js", "$/Release/branch1/global/js/main.js" ],
    result = filelist.reduce((r,file) => {
      let extension = file.substr(file.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
      if(['cs','ascx'].includes(extension)) {
        'Dot Net Files' in r ? r['Dot Net Files'].push(file) : r['Dot Net Files'] = [file];
      } else {
        'UI Files' in r ? r['UI Files'].push(file) : r['UI Files'] = [file];
      }
      return r;
    },{});

let output = Object.keys(result).reduce((s,k,i) => {
              return s += (i ? '\n\n' : '') + k + '\n________________________________\n' + result[k].join('\n');
            },'');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks Hassan! If I would like to add more extension in any group like (.ascx) at Dot Net files ?

Comment: Update this line `extension === 'cs'` to `['cs','ascx'].includes(extension)'`.

Comment: Thanks! Working fine. one more request if there was no UI or Dot net files then I do not want to show the text like "UI Files"....

Comment: Updated the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This "filelist" array is not valid. Every javaScript object must contain pair of key - value. I guess that the API you are using returns array of strings. So the easiest solution looks like this:

```
var fileString = "";
var filelist = [
    "$/Release/branch1/xmlfiles/Checkout.xml",
    "$/Release/branch1/xmlfiles/list.xml",
    "$/Release/branch1/global/Policy.ascx.designer.cs",
    "$/Release/branch1/global/Policy.ascx.cs",
    "$/Release/branch1/global/Policy.cs",
    "$/Release/branch1/global/img/bgwhite.jpg",
    "$/Release/branch1/global/js/init.js",
    "$/Release/branch1/global/js/main.js"
];

let uiFiles = [];
let csFiles = [];

for (let file of filelist) {
    let extension = file.split(".").pop();

    if (extension === "cs"){ 
        csFiles.push(file);
    }
    else {
        uiFiles.push(file);
    }
}

fileString += "UI Files \n-----------------------------------------\n";
for (let ui of uiFiles) {
    fileString += ui + "\n";
}

fileString += "\nDot Net Files \n-----------------------------------------\n";
for (let cs of csFiles) {
    fileString += cs + "\n";
}

console.log(fileString);
```